# window.on load function only executing on one single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this JS to fade in the wrapper when the page has loaded:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
  $(".wrapper").fadeIn();
  ...
});
```

It's working for one single page, but not for any other page.
There, the wrapper just doesn't fade in.
I tried a `console.log` but that didn't work aswell, so the function isn't executing at all.

The JS file is loaded via a PHP-include:

```
<?php
  include 'website/inc/head.php';
?>
```

And the `head.php` loads the `main.js`. That's the same for every page. But it doesn't execute the function on all of the pages except one.

By the way, I am using `$(window).on('load', function(){...});`, because I got a `a.indexOf is not a function` error when using `$(window).load(function(){...});`

---

You can check it out on [my website](https://tobiasgla.us/). Open the navigation and go to "Portfolio", where it is working.

Comment: May I know why you calling `$(window).on('load')` inside `$(document).ready()`? Can you try adding the script on index page rather than including in header and share your feedback then, Maybe then after I can help you.

Comment: Normally it should work as `document.ready` event fires before `window.load`. However, since your page is very light, it's possible the difference between them is so small that `window.load` fires while `document.ready` code is being read and parsed, so the binding is done after `load` already fired. The fix would be to place `$(window).on('load', ...)` outside of `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Oh makes sense. So if I added window load as a callback of document ready, it should work? Don't worry, I won't do that. Just wondering.

Comment: I wrote a more thorough explanation as an answer. Because usually pages are not light and connection is not fast, a lot of people make this mistake and it gets copied over and over. But the two (DOM building and resources loading) are parallel processes and, as you just experienced, there are cases where you can't bind for `w.load` inside `d.ready`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following structure in `main.js`:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // this code is applied when `document.ready` fires`

   $(window).on('load', function(){
     // this code is applied when `window.load` fires
     // if it was bound before `window.load` fired
   });

 })
```

The code inside `$(document).ready` is not applied when your `main.js` is parsed, but when `ready` fires on `$(document)`.

`$(document).ready()` fires when DOM has finished building.
(Basically wen the browser meets the `</html>` tag).

`$(window).load()` fires when all resources (scripts, styles, images, ...) have finished loading.

When `document.ready` event fires, the code inside that function is applied, while the browser continues to load resources.
If the page is very light and the connection to the server very fast, `window.load` will fire before the browser finished applying the code from `$(document)ready(...)`. So it might bind the listener on `window.load` after `window.load` already fired.

The solution is to bind the listener on `window.load` when `main.js` is parsed, not when `document.ready` fires:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   // this code is applied when `document.ready` fires`
 })
 $(window).on('load', function(){
   // this code is applied when `window.load` fires
   // and now you can be sure it has been bound before `window.load`
 });
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer!